# Change value of a variable inside a timer event Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, onclick

I am increasing value of a variable inside a timer.It is also inside a button onClick event.

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById('z_in').addEventListener('click', function () {
        zoom_level = 1;
    }, false);
    document.getElementById('z_out').addEventListener('click', function () {
        zoom_level = 3;
    }, false);
    document.getElementById('rotate').addEventListener('click', function () {
        angle = angle + 10;

    }, false);
    Find(db, minLon, maxLon, minLat, maxLat, zoom_level, angle, stage, layer, i);
    i++;
    //angle = 0;
    console.log();
}, 1000);
```

Here angle increases too much not ten by ten in every loop.What is the reason of this problem?

Comment: not enough code. can you make a fiddle...

Comment: You add an additional eventlistener each second. Thus angle increases by ten for every eventlistener added.

Comment: An offtopic question: which facts had spoken for it to pass complete javascript functions as parameters? In my eyes it is bad practise and makes it harder to read forign code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PPzQv/ you can see angle values in console.It does not increases ten by ten.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 So what can i do to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need listeners only when timer is active, you can use something like this:

```
var timer, i = 0, zoom_level = 1, angle = 0;
var z_in_el = document.getElementById('z_in');
var z_out_el = document.getElementById('z_out');
var rotate_el = document.getElementById('rotate');

function zoomIn(){
    zoom_level = 1;
}
function zoomOut(){
    zoom_level = 3;
}
function rotate(){
    angle += 10;
}

function startTimer(){
    addListeners();
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        Find(db, minLon, maxLon, minLat, maxLat, zoom_level, angle, stage, layer, i);
        console.log(i, zoom_level, angle);
    }, 1000); 
}

function stopTimer(){
    removeListeners();
    window.clearInterval(timer);
}

function addListeners(){
    z_in_el.addEventListener("click", zoomIn, false);
    z_out_el.addEventListener("click", zoomOut, false);
    rotate_el.addEventListener("click", rotate, false);
}

function removeListeners(){
    z_in_el.removeEventListener("click", zoomIn, false);
    z_out_el.removeEventListener("click", zoomOut, false);
    rotate_el.removeEventListener("click", rotate, false);
}
```

Use `startTimer()` to set interval or `stopTimer()` to remove it.

Comment: Fixed answer. Is it what you need?

Comment: Yep.Thank you so much Anton.That would be so very useful for me.